# How to use gdal to convert HDF multi-band file to a single GeoTiff file?

Tags: gdal, geotiff-tiff, gdal-translate, hdf

I have a multi-band HDF file that I want to convert to a single GeoTiff file, using free tools, preferably gdal.  I'm trying to use gdal_translate, but I either get back multiple output .tif files, or I get "subdatasets" errors.

When I use the -b flag to specify bands:

`gdal_translate -b 1 -b 2 -of GTiff input_image.hdf output_image.tif`

I get "subdatasets" errors:  "Input file contains subdatasets. Please, select one of them for reading."

And when I use the sds flag:

`gdal_translate -sds -of GTiff input_file.hdf output_file.tif`

I get back separate .tif files, one for each band in the input file.

How can I convert an HDF file into a single GeoTiff file using gdal?

Answer (score 2):

I also couldn't find a way to do it in one step... but using `-sds` like you did, followed by a `gdal_merge.py -separate` should work https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_merge.html#cmdoption-gdaladdo-separate

https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_translate.html#cmdoption-gdal-translate-sds

So this should work for you:

```bsh
gdal_translate -sds input_file.hdf tmp_outs.tif

gdal_merge.py -separate -o final_output.tif tmp_outs*tif

rm tmp_outs*tif
```

if your HDF5 subdatasets are different datatypes, specify which output type you want with `gdal_merge.py -ot Float32 ...`

Just to reference here what those options mean:

```
-sds

Copy all subdatasets of this file to individual output files. Use with formats like HDF that have subdatasets.



-separate

Place each input file into a separate band.
```

Comment: This worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to extract one band (subdataset) from your HDF file, than you need to specify the SUBDATASET name as part of the `gdal_translate` command. For instance, in the example described [here](http://www.gdal.org/frmt_hdf5.html), it is suggested to do the following:

```
gdal_translate HDF4_SDS:UNKNOWN:"AMOD021KM20061229043102.hdf":0 test_b0.tif

gdal_translate HDF4_SDS:UNKNOWN:"AMOD021KM20061229043102.hdf":1 test_b1.tif
```

You will need to update `HDF4_SDS:UNKNOWN:"AMOD021KM20061229043102.hdf` to reflect your own dataset, and you can retrieve this information using  `gdalinfo`.

Also, the [documentation](http://www.gdal.org/frmt_hdf5.html) on the GDAL website relating to the HDF format provides a lot of useful information and examples that should further assist you.

Comment: Thanks for responding.  I am trying to convert all of the bands/subdatasets from HDF format to GeoTiff.